# `select_if` behaves erratically with non-canonical column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using dplyr 0.5.0.

Consider the following two `tibble`s:

```
nice <- tibble(session=c(1,2), a=c(1,2), b=c(3,NA))
numeric_cols <- tibble(session=c(1,2), `1`=c(1,2), `2`=c(3,NA))
```

In the first case:

```
> select_if(nice, function(col) !any(is.na(col)))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
    num     a
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     2
```

In the second, I don't get the "good" complete column with numeric colname:

```
> select_if(numeric_cols, function(col) !any(is.na(col)))
# A tibble: 2 x 1
    num
* <dbl>
1     1
2     2
```

I have an issue with a much larger, very similarly structured `tibble` in my real analysis code, but I get this error:

```
    Error: Position must be between 0 and n
```

I have failed to make a small sharable example that produces this error, and I forgot how to use the R debugger. Let me know if it's worth my learning how to use it again.

Am I missing something? Is this a bug?

I am getting around this by simply using more "classic" R, but this is definitely a speed bump, and not as readable:

```
numeric_cols[
    summarize_all(numeric_cols, function(col) !any(is.na(col))) %>%
    unlist() ]
```

(If you are wondering, the reason I end up with numeric columns is because I'm spreading over an identifier column in order to use PCA on a matrix representation. I'd rather not change my identifiers.)

Answer (score 0):

`select_if` is just a simple wrapper for `select_`. The problem is if you run `select_(numeric_cols, .dots = "1")` it interprets the `"1"` as the column position, not the column name so `select_(numeric_cols, .dots = c("session", "1"))` (this is what your predicate function will filter to) is the same thing as `select_(numeric_cols, .dots = c("session", "session"))`, hence why you only ever get back the "session" column from numeric_cols.

I really recommend you rename your columns to something more appropriate, but if you must do this, this should work:

```
body(select_if)[[5]] <- quote(select(.data, one_of(vars)))
select_if(numeric_cols, function(col) !any(is.na(col)))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  session   `1`
    <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     1
2       2     2
```